# Selenium - Sandbox Paypal has refused to connect when trying to login by Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, paypal, sandbox

I faced an issue. When I'm trying to automate the step to login to the sandbox account from an iframe, but after I input the username/password and press login button, the error screen appears to inform that the sanbod.paypal.com has refused my connection.
[image]

Have anybody have the solution for this? Please help